# Authorization code grant

Tags: rest, authentication, spring-boot, authorization, spring-security-oauth2

I'm working on a REST API, that listens on localhost and I want to include Spring Security. Password grant and client credentials grant works perfectly and I can go check secured data from /smarthouse and /smarthouse2.

Although, when I try to use authorization code grant through postman, it gives me the same error and I have checked everywhere. My project is here: https://github.com/sharjak/Smarthouse. The action all happens in the demoapplication folder.

[Authorization code in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2emn.jpg)

My code for authorization and resource server:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .anonymous().disable()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated().and()
                    .formLogin();
            }
        }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

            clients.inMemory().withClient("my-trusted-client")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password","authorization_code","refresh_token", "implicit")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT","ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT","ROLE_USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                    .secret("secret")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(6000)
                    .and()

                    .withClient("my-client")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "implicit")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_USER")
                    .scopes("read","trust", "write")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(6000)
                    .and()

                    .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials","password")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_USER")
                    .scopes("read", "trust", "write")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                    .secret("secret")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(6000);
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
        }
    }
}
```

Code for Websecurity server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .anonymous().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/smarthouse", "smarthouse2", "/user").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .withUser("sander").password("Sander123").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore){
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }
}
```

Stacktrace when I try to log in with a user:

```
    org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorization can be completed.
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:138)
```

I'm quite a beginner, but it seems like a small problem to fix. Can anyone help me?

Comment: So what you want is to get the an access token using Postman?

Comment: Yes, the problem is, when I log in with the user, it doesn't give me the authorization code, but tells me that user must be authenticated. If I try to login from browser it gives me an error Authentication object was not found in the security context.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change your `configure` method from `WebSecurityConfig` to what follows:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login", "/favicon.ico",
            "/oauth/confirm_access", "/oauth/token", "/smarthouse",
            "smarthouse2", "/user").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    .csrf().disable();
```

Why do you want to disable anonymous access?
Another point is that the order the matchers are declared matters.

I have cloned your repo and doing it worked for me.

Comment: When I don't disable anonymous, it gives me an error access denied, user is anonymous. I tried it, but it still gives me the same error: An authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext. It seems like an endless loop, where user gets authenticated, then it redirects to authorization page, but fails to retrieve username and password and then redirects back to login page.

Comment: Just found the solution, I had wrong configuration in application.yml. Had to erase security.oauth2.resource.filer-order:3 and then it worked!